# Sum of two sets of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let L,K in $C[0,1]$ be compact. Prove or give a counter example that $L+k$ is compact.

Here $C[0,1]$ is the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the sup metric. I think it is compact and my strategy is to show every sequence has a converging subsequence. Let $x_n=f_n+g_n$ where $f_n$ is in L and $g_n$ is in k. Then both have a converging subsequence so $x_n$ has a converging subsequence since the uniform limit of the sum is the sum of the uniform limits. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Not really, note that a subsequence of $f_n$ is a set of indices $n_k$ such that $f_{n_k}$ converges, and a subsequence of $g_n$ is a set of indices $n_l$ such that $g_{n_l}$ converges. But you know nothing about these two sets of indices. Maybe they can be disjoint and hence, you cannot construct a subsequence of $f_n+g_n$ that converges that way (more explicitly, it could be possible that the subsequence of $f_n$ is the set of all odd indices whereas the subsequence of $g_n$ is the set of all even indices)

Comment: I was thinking you could take the subsequence for $f_n$ and then $g_n$ has a subsequence converging that corresponds to it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, this is how you're supposed to do it! Sorry if I misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: @Rummi That is the correct **idea**. It's not yet the correct answer, because you havent written it down strictly enough yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n + g_n$ be any sequence in $L+K$, where $\{ f_n \}_n \subset L$ and $\{ g_n \}_n \subset K$.

By compactness of $L$ there exists a subsequence $\{ f_{n_k} \}_k$ converging in $L$.

By compactness of $K$ there exists a subsequence $\{ g_{n_{k_l}}\}_l$ converging in $K$.

Since $\{ f_{n_{k_l}} \}_l$ is a subsequence of a converging sequence, it is convergent.

Thus, the subsequence $\{ f_{n_{k_l}} +g_{n_{k_l}} \}_l$ is convergent in $L+K$.